# Event handler not working on dynamically generated span with fn.on

Tags: jquery

I am creating a span with jquery. As that span wasn't live at the initial loop, event handler doesn't work. I searched for solution and made my code like this -

```
$(".uploaded_file_delete").on("click", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var fileurl = $(this).attr("data-fileurl");
        var data = { fileurl: fileurl, action: 'uploaded_file_delete' };
        var deleteonsuccess = $(this).parent();

        $.ajax({
      url: someaction.ajax_url,
      type: 'POST',
      data: data,
      cache: false,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {.....
```

This code works for hard coded spans but not dynamically generated ones. I am using jQuery 1.12.4. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With jQuery 1.12.4 you can use the newer [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) syntax. Just define the parent element (most parent would be `document` or `body`, but be as distinct as you could be) and add the element selector you want to add the event listener to as second parameter.

```
$(document).on( "click", ".uploaded_file_delete", function() {
  // ...
});
```

Comment: I am using wordpress and a lot of people are telling me not to replace wordpress core jquery version, it may affect functionality in the backend.

Comment: My bad, my jquery version is 1.12.4

Comment: Then you really should use `.on` instead of `.live`! @b0xed

Comment: Updated my answer @b0xed

Comment: Sorry just saw your updated answer. It works! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the event handler with live instead of on.

```
$('body').live('.uploaded_file_delete', function() {
    // Do stuff here...
});
```

Or with newer jQuery, the syntax is:

```
//                    ˇ What to click inside body
$('body').on('click', '.uploaded_file_delete', function() {
    // Do stuff here...
});
```

Comment: still doesn't work. I guess it's because of my jQuery version. Live works smoothly

Comment: I wish I could upvote you but I don't have 15 reputation to upvote. Thank you for helping :)

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `jQuery 1.4.1` you can use the [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) function

> **Description:** Attach an event handler for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future.

Something like this:

```
$(".uploaded_file_delete").live( "click", function(e){...} );
```

Nota that this function was deprecated on `jQuery 1.7` so if you upgrade to this version you should do it as Balázs Varga said